# Making a sorted linked list into a balanced binary search tree

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-search

My code works, but I need help on revising it to make it shorter and simple if possible on my main.cpp part ONLY. The other files is to make the program compile and work out if you want to see the output.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bintree.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace main_savitch_10;

list<int>* item_list = new list<int>;
list<int>* item_list2 = new list<int>;

list<int>* create_list()
{
     for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
     item_list -> push_front(i);
     item_list -> sort();
}
return item_list;
}

    list<int>* temp2 = new list<int>;
    template <class Item>
    binary_tree_node<int>* balanced_tree_rec(list<Item>* list,Item count)

{
    if(count <= 0)
         {return NULL;}
    if(list == NULL)
         {return NULL;}

     binary_tree_node<int>*left=balanced_tree_rec(list, count /2);
     binary_tree_node<int>* temp = new binary_tree_node<int>(list->front());
for(int i = 1; i <= count / 2; i++)
{
     temp = new binary_tree_node<int>( list->front() );
}
temp2 = list;
temp2 -> pop_front();

     binary_tree_node <int>* right = balanced_tree_rec(temp2, count - ( count / 2) -1);
     binary_tree_node<int>* root = new binary_tree_node<int>(temp -> data(), left, right);
return root;
}

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<int>* BBST(list<Item>* list)
{
     int count = list->size();
     return balanced_tree_rec(list, count);
}

template <class Item>
void push(Item& test)
{
     item_list2 -> push_back(test);
}

template<class Item>
void print(binary_tree_node<Item>* tree)
{
     if(tree)
     {
     cout << tree -> data() << " ";
     printT(tree -> left());
     printT(tree -> right());
     }
}
int main()
{
        printf("The Balance Binary Search Tree\n");

     list<int>* a = create_list();

     binary_tree_node<int>* p = BBST(a);

     print(p, 1);

   return 0;
}
```

**bintree.h header file**

```
// FILE: bintree.h (part of the namespace main_savitch_10)
// PROVIDES: A template class for a node in a binary tree and functions for
// manipulating binary trees. The template parameter is the type of data in
// each node.
//
// TYPEDEF for the binary_tree_node<Item> template class:
// Each node of the tree contains a piece of data and pointers to its
// children. The type of the data (binary_tree_node<Item>::value_type) is
// the Item type from the template parameter. The type may be any of the C++
// built-in types (int, char, etc.), or a class with a default constructor,
// and an assignment operator.
//
// CONSTRUCTOR for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
// binary_tree_node(
// const item& init_data = Item( ),
// binary_tree_node<Item>* init_left = NULL,
// binary_tree_node<Item>* init_right = NULL
// )
// Postcondition: The new node has its data equal to init_data,
// and it's child pointers equal to init_left and init_right.
//
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
// const item& data( ) const <----- const version
// and
// Item& data( ) <----- non-const version
// Postcondition: The return value is a reference to the data from
// this binary_tree_node.
//
// const binary_tree_node* left( ) const <----- const version
// and
// binary_tree_node* left( ) <----- non-const version
// and
// const binary_tree_node* right( ) const <----- const version
// and
// binary_tree_node* right( ) <----- non-const version
// Postcondition: The return value is a pointer to the left or right child
// (which will be NULL if there is no child).
//
// void set_data(const Item& new_data)
// Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new data.
//
// void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_link)
// and
// void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_link)
// Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new link
// to a child.
//
// bool is_leaf( )
// Postcondition: The return value is true if the node is a leaf;
// otherwise the return value is false.
//
// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS to maniplulate binary tree nodes:
// tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
// void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
// node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
// Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the function f has been
// applied to the contents of *node_ptr and all of its descendants, using
// an in-order traversal.
// Note: BTNode may be a binary_tree_node or a const binary tree node.
// Process is the type of a function f that may be called with a single
// Item argument (using the Item type from the node).
//
// tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
// void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Same as the in-order function, except with a post-order traversal.
//
// tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
// void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Same as the in-order function, except with a pre-order traversal.
//
// template <class Item, class SizeType>
// void print(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth)
// Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
// node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree). If the pointer is
// not NULL, then depth is the depth of the node pointed to by node_ptr.
// Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the contents of *node_ptr
// and all its descendants have been written to cout with the << operator,
// using a backward in-order traversal. Each node is indented four times
// its depth.
//
// template <class Item>
// void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr)
// Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
// be NULL for the empty tree).
// Postcondition: All nodes at the root or below have been returned to the
// heap, and root_ptr has been set to NULL.
//
// template <class Item>
// binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr)
// Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
// be NULL for the empty tree).
// Postcondition: A copy of the binary tree has been made, and the return
// value is a pointer to the root of this copy.
//
// template <class Item>
// size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr)
// Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
// node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
// Postcondition: The return value is the number of nodes in the tree.

#ifndef BINTREE_H
#define BINTREE_H
#include <cstdlib> // Provides NULL and size_t

namespace main_savitch_10
{

template <class Item>
class binary_tree_node
{
public:
   // TYPEDEF
   typedef Item value_type;
   // CONSTRUCTOR
   binary_tree_node(
   const Item& init_data = Item( ),
   binary_tree_node* init_left = NULL,
   binary_tree_node* init_right = NULL
   )
   {
   data_field = init_data;
   left_field = init_left;
   right_field = init_right;
   }
   // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
   Item& data( ) { return data_field; }
   binary_tree_node* left( ) { return left_field; }
   binary_tree_node* right( ) { return right_field; }
   void set_data(const Item& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
   void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_left) { left_field = new_left; }
   void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_right) { right_field = new_right; }
   // CONST MEMBER FUNCTIONS
   const Item& data( ) const { return data_field; }
   const binary_tree_node* left( ) const { return left_field; }
   const binary_tree_node* right( ) const { return right_field; }
   bool is_leaf( ) const
   { return (left_field == NULL) && (right_field == NULL); }
private:
   Item data_field;
   binary_tree_node *left_field;
   binary_tree_node *right_field;
};

// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item>:
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void print(binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth);

template <class Item>
void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr);

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr);

template <class Item>
std::size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr);
}

#include "bintree.template"
#endif
```

**bintree.template:**

```
// FILE: bintree.template
// IMPLEMENTS: The binary_tree node class (see bintree.h for documentation).
#include <cassert> // Provides assert
#include <cstdlib> // Provides NULL, std::size_t
#include <iomanip> // Provides std::setw
#include <iostream> // Provides std::cout

namespace main_savitch_10
{
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
if (node_ptr != NULL)
{
inorder(f, node_ptr->left( ));
f( node_ptr->data( ) );
inorder(f, node_ptr->right( ));
}
}

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
if (node_ptr != NULL)
{
postorder(f, node_ptr->left( ));
postorder(f, node_ptr->right( ));
f(node_ptr->data( ));
}
}

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
if (node_ptr != NULL)
{
f( node_ptr->data( ) );
preorder(f, node_ptr->left( ));
preorder(f, node_ptr->right( ));
}
}

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void print(binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth)
// Library facilities used: iomanip, iostream, stdlib
{
if (node_ptr != NULL)
{
print(node_ptr->right( ), depth+1);
std::cout << std::setw(4*depth) << ""; // Indent 4*depth spaces.
std::cout << node_ptr->data( ) << std::endl;
print(node_ptr->left( ), depth+1);
}
}

template <class Item>
void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
   binary_tree_node<Item>* child;
   if (root_ptr != NULL)
   {
   child = root_ptr->left( );
   tree_clear( child );
   child = root_ptr->right( );
   tree_clear( child );
   delete root_ptr;
   root_ptr = NULL;
   }
}

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
   binary_tree_node<Item> *l_ptr;
   binary_tree_node<Item> *r_ptr;

   if (root_ptr == NULL)
   return NULL;
   else
   {
   l_ptr = tree_copy( root_ptr->left( ) );
   r_ptr = tree_copy( root_ptr->right( ) );
   return
       new binary_tree_node<Item>( root_ptr->data( ), l_ptr, r_ptr);
   }
}

template <class Item>
size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
if (node_ptr == NULL)
return 0;
else
return
   1 + tree_size(node_ptr->left( )) + tree_size(node_ptr->right( ));
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Keep in mind that you will likely receive advice/suggestions on other parts of your code besides `main.cpp`. I hope you get some great answers!

Comment: Is that indentation screwed by posting, or does it look like that in your editor too? If you are using it like this, why? Indentation helps a lot to keep track of different scopes, I can't imagine working with unintended source.

Comment: Its the posting.

Comment: Try to fix it. Just paste whole source from your IDE into edit box, then select it all (shift+[page]up/down), and Ctrl+K to make it "code formatted". It should then looks in the same way, as in your IDE (check preview before posting).

Comment: Possibly the [Day–Stout–Warren algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm) may be of some interest for you (especially its second phase).

Answer (score 2):

**Shortening main.cpp**
Move all the template functions into either bintree.h or bintree.template.
Templates are for generic use and really shouldn't be in the file where you
are using them.
Perhaps make the template functions in main.cpp part of your binary tree class.

**using namespace std;**
Namespaces were invented to prevent the collision of function names from different
sources. The code contains a specific namespace, main_savitch_10. Within
main_savitch_10 std:: is actually used. It would be less confusing to anyone
that had to maintain this code if the namespaces were fully specified within
all the code. Take a look at this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

This is especially true in your function balanced_tree_rec(), this
would be a lot more readable and maintainable if it was declared

```
binary_tree_node<int>* balanced_tree_rec(std::list<Item>* list,Item count)
```

**Global Variables**
The use of global variables is generally frowned on. There may be a few valid uses
of them, but the use of global variables within a template function is not
portable and not maintainable. It effectively breaks the template function.

```
list<int>* item_list = new list<int>;
list<int>* item_list2 = new list<int>;
list<int>* temp2 = new list<int>;
```

template 
binary_tree_node* balanced_tree_rec(list* list,Item count)

```
    temp2 = list;
    temp2 -> pop_front();
```

template  void push(Item& test)

```
    item_list2 -> push_back(test);
```

**Use Meaningful Names**
Quite often in the software development world, others have to maintain the code
we write, variable names and function names should clearly indicate what they
are some examples that would be a problem are `BBST()`, `list`, `p`, and `a`;

**Standard File Extensions**
There are several discussions on Stack Overflow about the proper extension for
a template file, you might want to look at these ([convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264656/c-template-implementation-file-extension-convention), [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307914/what-is-the-correct-file-extension-for-a-c-template-implementation-file) and [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526299/c-templates-declare-in-h-define-in-hpp)). I personally would either add it within the name space section of bintree.h or create a bintree.hpp. The boost libraries use hpp. The reason I would combine both files into one is that the template file by itself won't compile without the bintree.h.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory Management**

You're not keeping trace of your pointers to allocated memory.  This means you're leaking memory.  Generally, every `new` in your program should be paired with a delete.

Looking at this loop:

```
binary_tree_node<int>* temp = new binary_tree_node<int>(list->front());
for (int i = 1; i <= count / 2; i++)
{
    temp = new binary_tree_node<int>(list->front());
}
```

You are creating a new instance of `binary_tree_node` for over and over again.  The only reference you have to these created objects is being overwritten each time you assign to the temp pointer, which means the memory is lost and can't be recovered.  To achieve the same thing, with only a single memory allocation you could do this:

```
int temp_list_head = list->front();    
for (int i = 1; i <= count / 2; i++)
{
    temp_list_head = list->front();
}
binary_tree_node<int>* temp = new binary_tree_node<int>(temp_list_head);
```

You have a similar issue at the end of your code where you're not cleaning up after the tree you've constructed.  You're missing this call at the end of main:

```
tree_clear(p);
```